# How to change Azure portal VMSS scale condition "Scale to a specific instance count"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I want to increase/decrease VMSS instance count from scaling. I got commands to do so, but it did not affect permanent changes.
I want command in powershell.

For Eg.
I have increase instance count by following two commands.

```
Command 1 : 
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $resourceGrpName -VMScaleSetName $vmssName -SkuCapacity 2

Command 2 : 
InlineScript{
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $using:resourceGrpName -
VMScaleSetName $using:vmssName  
$vmss.Sku.Capacity = 2
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $using:resourceGrpName -Name 
$using:vmssName -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
}
```

In both above cases, instance count increases and in short period of time after creating instance it again decreases to its previous value.

Anybody know, how to change "Scale to a specific instance count"?

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you need more help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot, ScaleSet might be decreasing because you have Auto-scaling turned on based on CPU metric. This means that only 1 instance will be running if CPU is less than 25%

If you do not want the system to automatically scale down, remove the auto-scaling setting.

Answer (score 1):

For now, Azure PowerShell does **not** support to create Azure VMSS scale rules based on schedule.

> To create autoscale rules based on a schedule rather than host
>   metrics, use the Azure portal. Schedule-based rules **cannot**
>   currently be created with Azure PowerShell.

For more information about autoscale based on a schedule, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-powershell#autoscale-based-on-a-schedule).

Comment: what does this has to do with schedule?

Comment: @4c74356b41  Based on my knowledge, scale to a specific instance count same as scale based on schedule.